# Desativar botão depois de inserir

Tags: javascript, html

Pretendo que o botão, depois de clicar para inserir, fique bloqueado. Só posso inserir uma vez cada botão, que representa uma tarefa.

Botão:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="return confirm('Pretende registar esta atividade?');this.disabled=true;">Pequeno Almoço</button>
```

Estou a tentar com `this.disabled=true;` mas depois de clicar e inserir na base de dados, fica na mesma ativo.

script na página:

```js
function myFunction() {
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
document.getElementById("IniciarTarefa1").value = dateTime;
}

(function ($) {$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#form,#form1").submit(function(e){ 
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./conexaoteste",
        data: $("#form,#form1").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        dataType: "json",
            success: function (data){      
   }, 
            error: function(data){
                $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
            },
 });

});
});
```

Comment: Quando voce fala que insere na base de dados, como voce faz isso? voce redireciona?

Comment: @LocalHost faço via `post` com `ajax`

Comment: Então em vez de fazer $("#form,#form1").submit(function(e)); coloque em uma função! você não precisa do submit, e no botão chame essa função ou adicione um evento ao botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize um if e retire o `;` entre o `if` e o `this.disabled`:

```html
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="if(confirm('Pretende registar esta atividade?')) this.disabled=true;">Pequeno Almoço</button>
```

Isso irá criar uma condição no `confirm` onde o `if` só será acessado se você clicar em `OK`.

Comment: com a condição resolveu o meu problema, mas ao testar com mais um botão detetei um problema. Se clicar em duas tarefas e fizer `Ok` insere e desativa o botão, mas se na terceira tarefa clicar no botão e fizer `cancelar` volta a ativar os dois botões anteriores e não devia.

Comment: Então vc está fazendo diferente, porque o `this` se refere ao botão clicado.

Comment: o que está acontecer é que quando faço `cancelar` atualiza a página. Tenho o botão como colocou acima

Comment: Mas se vc atualizar a página os botões voltam ao normal. Não há nada de errado nisso.

Comment: sim, eu sei. E como não quero que atualize a página enquanto registo as tarefas nunca atualizo a página até finalizar o registo de todas as tarefas. Mas o que está acontecer é, se clicar em `ok` nunca atualiza a página, mas se clicar em `cancelar` atualiza  a página, como posso fazer para não atualizar ao clicar em `cancelar`?

Comment: O `confirm` não atualiza a página... ao clicar em `cancelar` o janela de diálogo simplesmente se fecha.

Comment: no meu código está atualizar, não consigo perceber então o motivo de o estar a fazer.

Comment: Deve ter alguma outro script gerando esse comportamento indesejado.

Comment: @brunox99x adicionei os scripts que tenho na página à pergunta

Comment: E esse $("#form,#form1").submit(function(e) ? por acaso seu button não esta dentro de um form com id form ou form1? ao clicar no botão esse script faz o submit dos dados e recarrega a pagina!

Comment: Quando você coloca um button em um form e não declara o tipo dele assume-se que é um type="submit" adicione type="button" em seus botoes para que não atualizem a pagina ao cancelar.

Comment: @brunox99x ao colocar `type="button"` deixa de atualizar a página ao cancelar, mas também deixa de inserir na base de dados. Resolvo um problema mas cria outro

Comment: Então você não deve usar um formulário se quiser enviar dados sem atualizar a página e em etapas. Par isso use Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite, remova o return no inicio:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="confirm('Pretende registar esta atividade?');this.disabled=true;">Pequeno Almoço</button>
```

Ha se quiser guardar um retorno do alert podes fazer assim:

```
<script>
     var a = null;
</script>
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="a = confirm('Pretende registar esta atividade?');this.disabled=true;">Pequeno Almoço</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="alert(a);">Ver variável</button>
```

Comment: ao remover o `return` surge o problema que ao aparecer o alerta do `confirm` se clicar em cancelar desativa o botão, e não pretendo isso, pretendo que só desative se inserir uma vez essa atividade. Outro problema ao clicar desativa o botão, mas ao desativar já não insere na base de dados

Comment: Então coloque assim this.disabled = confirm('Pretende registar esta atividade?'); só vai desativar se clicar em sim!

Comment: era mesmo isso que precisava. Obrigado